# I have a question about 'conditional structure'

Tags: conditional-constructions

Under sentence is on my textbook.

> If I were going to Fiji next week, I would be taking my scuba diving gear with me.
>
> = I am not going to Fiji and I am not going to take my scuba gear with me.

And I just saw this sentence googling.

> If I were going to have a child, I would get a copy of this book first.

1. I'd like to know if this sentence means 'I am not going to have a baby'.
   I think 2nd sentence is just about imaginary situation,
   but compared to 1st sentence, 2nd sentence could mean 'I am not going to have a baby'.
   What is the right meaning?
2. What if I use ' if i am going to have a child, I will get a copy of this book first'?
   which one is right or more common?

Comment: *I am not going to go to Fiji* is not natural! I'd say *'I am not going to Fiji'*

Comment: @MaulikV Thanks for your concern, I just modified.

Comment: @Maulik: *I am not going to go* is perfectly fine and idiomatic.

Comment: @DanBron while *I'm not going to go...* sounds okay, adding other words *I'm not going to go **to** Fiji* tickles me! :(

Comment: @MaulikV Doesn't bother me; the other day I said something along the lines of "I'm not going to go to the store, it's freezing out." (PS: *tickles me* usually means *amuses me*, not *irritates me*).

Comment: We use these kinds of conditionals when we think hypothetically. When we are thinking about impossible things, or things that we know will not happen, we have to think hypothetically. This does NOT mean that when we think hypothetically, we think something won't happen!! (Just like the fact that I breathe when I sleep does not mean I sleep when I breathe!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first sentence you specify a point in time:

> If I were going to Fiji **next week**

I know that you are not going to go because then you would have said "*when I go* to Fiji next week..."

But in the second sentence you *don't* specify a particular time:

> If I were going to have a child

So you're talking about a hypothetical future. You're not sure if you'll have a child, but if you do then you would buy this book.

If you said:

> If I were going to have a child next week, I would get a copy of this book first.

Then the same logic you applied to the first sentence can be applied to this one.